# How to check if set((2,range(2,3))) is subset of set((1,range(2,100)))

Tags: python-3.x, set, range

How can I check if two sets which contain ranges are subsets of each other ?

```
set((2,range(2,3))).issubset(set((1,range(2,100))))
-->[False]

set((range(2,3))).issubset(set((range(2,100))))
-->[False]
```

But that's true indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what the set looks like:

```
>>> set((2, range(2, 5)))
{range(2, 5), 2}
```

As you can see, the range object is an actual element of the set. An element `3` for example wouldn’t be in that set, because it’s just contained within the range that is in the set.

What you want to do is create a set from a range by iterating over the numbers in the range, and then adding a few more numbers:

```
>>> a = set((2,)).union(set(range(2, 3)))
>>> b = set((1,)).union(set(range(2, 100)))
>>> a.issubset(b)
True
```

Note that I pass the individual numbers as a *tuple* while the ranges are passed as a single argument to `set()`.

Comment: But is this efficient for big ranges ?

Comment: No, not really, as you need to put every element from the range into the actual set while ranges themselves are just “virtual” sequences. If you wanted to support both sets and ranges, you could easily write some own logic though. But you can’t use set’s built-in logic for that.